# Have the total price of the registration available in the @foreach

Tags: laravel

I have this query below to get the next registrations of a user in a conference:

```
$nextRegistrations = $user->registrations()->whereHas('conference', function ($query) {
            $query->where('end_date', '>', now());
        })->paginate($pageLimit);
```

Then to show the data of each registration of the user:

```
@foreach($nextRegistrations as $nextRegistration)
    @if(!empty($nextRegistration->conference) || !empty($nextRegistration->conference->start_date))
        <h5>{{optional($nextRegistration->conference)->name}}</h5>
        ...
    @endif
@endforeach
```

I want to show a button "Remove registration" only if the total price of the registration is "0", like:

```
@if ($nextRegistration->totalPrice > 0)
    <a href="{{route('registration.remove', ['regID'=> $nextRegistration->id])}}" class="btn btn-outline-primary"> Remove</a>
@endif
```

To get the total price of a specific registration the query can be like below. But do you know how to use this code with the $nextRegistrations query so that the  $nextRegistrations have the information of the total price of the registration available in the @foreach?

```
$registration = Registration::with('participants', 'participants.registration_type')->find($regID);

$total = $registration->participants->sum(function ($participant) {
    return $participant->registration_type->price;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to calculate the total price on the SQL query itself, one way to achieve this is following —

The `totalPrice` of a `registration` is dependent on the `participants` & `registration_type` as you've pointed out in your code. So eager load these relationships with the initial query so that it's available during the `sum` calculation.

So the query would be:

```
$nextRegistrations = $user->registrations()
                          ->with('participants.registration_type')
                          ->whereHas(
                              'conference', 
                              function ($query) {
                                  $query->where('end_date', '>', now());
                              }
                           )->paginate($pageLimit);
```

Now, define an accessor to the `Registration` model named `totalPrice` like this:

```
/**
 * Get the total price attribute of the registration.
 *
 * @return float $totalPrice
 */
public function getTotalPriceAttribute()
{
    // Here the assumption is `participants` relation will
    // be available by eager load to prevent n+1 query
    return $this->participants->sum(function ($participant) {
        return $participant->registration_type->price;
    });
}
```

Now you could access the `totalPrice` from an already loaded `$registration` model by `$registration->totalPrice`. Laravel will call the accessor for you. You can even auto load the `totalPrice` field for every `$registration` model by adding this to the `$appends` array to the `Registration` model.

```
/**
 * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = ['totalPrice'];
```

This is useful during serialization i.e. serving from an API.

Answer (score 0):

Define this function in your Registration Model

```
public function getTotalPriceAttribute() {

    // if relation is not loaded already, let's do it first
    if ( ! array_key_exists('participants', $this->relations)) 
         $this->load('participants', 'participants.registration_type');      

    return $this->participants->sum(function ($participant) {
        return $participant->registration_type->price;
    });
}
```

In controller

```
$nextRegistrations = Registration::with('participants', 'participants.registration_type')
                     ->where('user_id', $user->id)
                     ->whereHas('conference', function ($query) {
                         $query->where('end_date', '>', now());
                     })->paginate($pageLimit);
```

View

```
@foreach($nextRegistrations as $nextRegistration)
    @if(!empty($nextRegistration->conference) || !empty($nextRegistration->conference->start_date))
        <h5>{{optional($nextRegistration->conference)->name}}</h5>
        ...
    @endif
    @if ($nextRegistration->totalPrice > 0)
        <a href="{{route('registration.remove', ['regID'=> $nextRegistration->id])}}" class="btn btn-outline-primary"> Remove</a>
    @endif 
@endforeach
```